# Zebra Printer Bluetooth COM PORT

Tags: printing, bluetooth, windows-7-x64, zebra-printers

I have strange behavior with a Zebra printer when connecting via Bluetooth.

1. Connect the device against a port using BLUETOOTH, f.e : COM 8
2. Hyperterminal connects to the COM8 port without problems.
3. Install the ZEBRA Printer against the COM port : "Add Local Printer against existing Port"
4. Print Test page .
5. I can no longer connect to the COM port.

It is as if once you print something, the COM port is occupied, and it is not possible to send commands...
The enviroment is a Windows7 x64 PC  (*same behaviour in Windows7 x32 ,Windows 10*)

Tested Bluetooh stacks :

1. Microsoft
2. [Toshiba](https://superuser.com/questions/408180/alternative-bluetooth-stacks-for-windows-7-64bit)

[Example  of Bluetooth pairing of a Zebra Printer](https://km.zebra.com/kb/index?page=content&id=SO8712)

**DIFFERENCES BETWEEN TOSHIBA AND MICROSOFT BLUETOOTH STACK:**

With the Toshiba bluetoth stack it is possible to have the same device linked in two different COM ports. This is possible:

1. Pair/Link, f.e. Device X to Port COM X
2. Pair/Link, f. e Device X to Port COM Y

This way I can install the printer against the COM Y port.
By the COM X port I can launch send without problems .....

With the  of Microsoft Bluetooth stack is not be able to have the same device linked to two ports ....